# Where is the captcha box?

Tags: support, captcha

This is what I see when I try to submit a question to the mathematica.stackexchange.com site:

[image: Human verification box]

I am unable to find any captcha boxes.

I should add that I'm using Google Chrome on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Do you have any extentions? Try in incognito mode (Ctrl+Shift+N)

Comment: Hm. After fiddling with changing line statements and reclicking "post" I was able to avoid the verification step. Now I can't get it back to try your step.

Comment: Go to https://meta.stackexchange.com/nocaptcha

Comment: Ah yes! A box appears! Ok, so it looks like the solution is to post using incognito mode. Thanks.

Comment: Well there is one extension blocking it. you could try disabling all then enable each in turn to find out which one is the probelm

Comment: Yes, in this case it was the mouseless stack-calculator extension. I hardly use it anyways, so I guess I'll dump it.

Comment: @Tim, I can't accept your answer unless you expand it a bit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often extensions can mess with stuff. Try Incognito mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>).

If that fixes it, try disabling all the extensions in normal mode and disable each in turn to find which is the problem.

Comment: Sometimes, but more often an extension just does weird stuff.